# How much should I know about Category theory for A&M introduction to commutative algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, book-recommendation

I'm recently reading A&M introduction to commutative algebra, and I found that in the text, they implicitly assume I know some basic notions about category theory (for example, in the exercise, they assume I know about Tor functor). Should I know some of Category theory to read this text? If so, could you suggest some textbook or something for that?

Comment: I think you don't need it. Where do they presume you know about Tor functors?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer In chapter 2 exercises

Comment: Previous to ex. 24, ch.2 it reads "In these Exercises it will be assumed that the reader is familiar with the definition and basic properties of the Tor functor. " That does not seem very *implicit* to me... as @JeroenvanderMeer says, I think the book is pretty self contained in that aspect. Iirc it is even mentioned in the preface that they deliberately ignored some homological aspects of the subject to keep the book succinct

Comment: "The compromise we have adopted is to use elementary homological
methods--exact sequences, diagrams, etc.-but to stop short of any results
requiring a deep study of homology. In this way we hope to prepare the ground
for a systematic course on homological algebra which the reader should undertake if he wishes to pursue algebraic geometry in any depth."

Comment: (Regardless, if you want to learn some category theory I would recommend Emily Riehl's [Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf). It's beautifully written and has tons of examples from different places.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll be fine with not knowing category theory. As guidoar also says, you may want to be acquainted with basic notions like exact sequences and diagrams. It is true that some exercises in section 2 require knowledge of Tor-groups, but if you don't have that knowledge, you can probably safely skip these exercises.